# when use the useLocation show React Router caught the following error during render Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a SubPaySuccess public component in react app like this:

```
const SubPaySuccess: React.FC = () => {

    const location = useLocation();
    if (location.search == null) {
        return (<div className="pay-success-body">
            <h1>Pay Failed!</h1>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

when run into this line `const location = useLocation();`,  show error:

```
ract-dom.production.min.js:189 Error
    at router.js:270:11
    at dp (index.js:141:79)
    at Fp (SubPaySuccess.tsx:10:22)
    at ki (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at kl (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at Ec (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at ic (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at ac (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
ps @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
a.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:190
ja @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
Sl @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
El @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
yl @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
wc @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
ac @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
w @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
T @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
hooks.tsx:597 React Router caught the following error during render Error
    at router.js:270:11
    at dp (index.js:141:79)
    at Fp (SubPaySuccess.tsx:10:22)
    at ki (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at kl (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at Ec (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at ic (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at ac (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429) {c
```

this is the route `"react-router-dom": "^6.11.1"` define:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../page/index/Home';
import Login from '../page/user/login/Login';
import { SubPaySuccess } from 'rd-component';

const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />
  },
  {
    path: "/product/pay/success",
    element: <SubPaySuccess />
  },
  {
    path: "/user/login",
    element: <Login />
  }
]);

export default routes;
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? the error was throw from `useLocation()`. BTW: the SubPaySuccess component was not define in current project, it defined in third party public lib.

Comment: Can you link to the lib please? This looks like whats happens when you get 2 versions of react router at the same time. If the third party lib uses a different version, that would explain it. There are ways around it, but would need to see the library.

Comment: I am tried this way to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234908/why-i-get-this-error-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usestate-on-my

Comment: If you can link to the third party lib i will be able to identify which package is causing the issue

Comment: this package named react-router-dom caused this issue.