# React useState cannot read properties of null ("reading useState") while consume the component in VueJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hooks, vuejs2

I have a simple React Component using **typescript** compiled through **webpack** so it can use as remote components using module federation.

Here is my webpack configuration

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
// import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
const path = require('path');
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js", ".json",".tsx","ts"],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom')
    },
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
      configFile: '../../tsconfig.json',
      
    })]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-typescript"],
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        './Configuration': '../../src/widgets/configurations/branding/page.tsx'
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    })
  ],
};
```

Now the build made successfully but when consuming the remote component in VueJS 2.7 getting this error. We are using VueJS with typescript so here is my config **vue.config.js**

```
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'tvs-shell',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          host: 'host@http://localhost:50016/remoteEntry.js'
        },
]
```

I am using **vuera-ts** package to show React Component in VueJS Here is my vuejs- **Consumer** code **ts** code

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Button from 'host/Configuration';
import { ReactInVue } from 'vuera-ts';

@Component({
  components:{
    TestCompInVue,
  },
})
<script>
```

**vue**

```
<template>
    <TestCompInVue />
</template>
```

Any help or suggestion will be helpful . If I remove the **useState** it works perfectly fine. But once added getting this subject error. Here is the attach screenshot[image]

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234908/why-i-get-this-error-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usestate-on-my
check if the answer there helps.